# When should I use the [:] to append the result?

Tags: python

I have two code examples, both of which work the same:

```
class Solution(object):
    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        m = len(nums)
        ans = []
        def solve(lst, tmp):

            if len(tmp) == m:
                ans.append(tmp)
            
            for i in range(len(lst)):
                solve(lst[:i]+lst[i+1:], tmp + [lst[i]])
        
        solve(nums, [])
        
        return ans
```

and this one:

```
class Solution(object):
    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        ans = []
        l = len(nums)
        def solve(tmp, c):
            """ why should I use tmp[:] here? instead of tmp?"""
            if len(tmp) == l:
                ans.append(tmp[:])
            for i in c:
                if c[i] > 0:
                    tmp.append(i)
                    c[i] -= 1
                    solve(tmp, c)
                    c[i] += 1
                    tmp.pop()
        solve([], Counter(nums))
        
        return ans
```

For the line I highlight, if I change it from `tmp[:]` to `tmp`, then it will be a list of empty list?

I want to know when should I append a copy of list, and when should I just append the tmpo list?

Comment: copy to a new list so that changes to original list won't affect the new.

Comment: so for the first one why I dont need to do a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `tmp.append(i)`, you're implicitly modifying the reference of that list that would be stored inside of `ans`. When you do a copy, that wouldn't happen

For the first answer, the addition is returning a new list, not appending directly to `tmp`

To get a similar behavior, you'd have to do

```
tmp += [lst[i]]
solve(lst[:i]+lst[i+1:], tmp)
```

Comment: can I say that addition is different from ```append()```? it will create a new list?

Comment: That's correct.